# I did a factory reset on windows 7 and now I can't boot into Ubuntu, how can I fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I switched over to Ubuntu about a month ago after Windows 7 was corrupted and wouldn't boot anymore. I recently decided to restore Windows 7 so I could play a game on it. Unfortunately I had no restore points so I had to completely reformat the whole thing. Now when I turn on my computer I no longer get the option to boot into Ubuntu or Windows 7, it just boots straight to Windows. When I check the C drive I still have the 20 gigs I set aside for Ubuntu partitioned off. I'm thinking that Windows 7 reformatted the entire hard drive rather than just it's own partition, but I'm asking here to confirm my fears and make sure it isn't a fixable problem. I'd really like to avoid having to reinstall Ubuntu if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu recommends installing Windows first since it will overwrite your boot sector:

> A Windows OS should be installed first, because its bootloader is very
>   particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive,
>   wiping out any data stored on it. If Windows isn't already installed,
>   install it first.

So it sounds like you need to recovering GRUB after reinstalling Windows. Ubuntu provides the instructions at this location:

[Reinstalling GRUB 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

I hope this will help you. Good luck.